# resize form in panel not working

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am loading a form into a panel by using the below code, problem is if the main window is resized the form doesn't resize with it.

```
frm = new frmShopFloorMonitor();
            frm.TopLevel = false;
            frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            frm.AutoSize = true;
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(frm);
            pnlMain.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
            frm.Show();
            frm.BringToFront();
```

any suggestions?

The ribbon control is the one found here : http://officeribbon.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why are you loading a form inside a panel?

Wouldn't it be nice if the content of the Form becomes a User Control then it can be loaded into a panel or if required on a form.

Comment: The reason for this is I have a ribbon control on the mdi parent and need the child title bar to appear under the ribbon control, to do that I found the above code, do you have an example of what you mean?

Comment: I don't think showing a form inside a panel is the right way ahead, didn't you face issues like focus? The solution I suggested assumed you would not want the Title bar etc. I suggested doing away with Form and using just the controls on that form, which obviously is not what you want...

Comment: Can't repro.  I would think AutoSize should be false though since you are controlling the size with the dock fill.  Otherwise, from the comments, it might have something to do with the ribbon control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead I opted to do a different hack, stick with MDIParent and child relations and do the following :

1) Add a menu strip onto the MDIParent form and change its Visible value to false
2) Change the following on the MDIChild forms to false : ControlBox, MaximizeBox, MinimizeBox, ShowIcon, ShowInTaskBar
3) Change the MDIChild forms frame border to none.

This allowed me to create a child window maximized without the title bar showing!

Comment: "I did it another way" does not answer the original question.

Comment: @HansPassant neither does walking backwards to a destination but it still gets you there!  The question is still open for answers if someone can resolve the issue.